# If user edit the field, the proposals buttons should show message. How to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, conditional-statements

What i want to do is like the following picture.

[image]

Here's my code for that part.

```
<div class="row nomargin">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
          <%= u.label :email, I18n.t("me.business.edit.email"), class: "control-label" %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-6">
          <%= u.text_field :email, placeholder: I18n.t("me.business.edit.email"), class: "form-control", id: "listing_owner_email" %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
          <%= render 'admin/listings/edit/comment/send_proposal_btns' %>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: by default proposals field should be activated and when user edit any of these fields , it should be activated . is it ?

Comment: @htoo Question is not clear. can you show us code sample, or what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Vishal >>> Yes.

Comment: @Gabbar, the question is as Vishal said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you will need to add some javascript to make this happen.  There are a number of ways to do it, but I'd start with something simple, like an on-page reference and use a library like JQuery.  so to add this functionality for your email field, it would look something like:

```
<div class="row nomargin">
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    <%= u.label :email, I18n.t("me.business.edit.email"), class: "control-label" %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-6">
    <%= u.text_field :email, placeholder: I18n.t("me.business.edit.email"), class: "form-control", id: "listing_owner_email" %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
    <%= render 'admin/listings/edit/comment/send_proposal_btns' %>
    <div id='btn_disabled_message' style='display:none'>
      You need to save the new address/phone before you can send.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  function disableProposalBtn() {
    $('#id_of_proposal_button').attr("disabled", "disabled");  //disable button
    $('#btn_disabled_message').toggle(true) // show hidden message
  }

  // handle email and mobile changed event
  $( "#listing_owner_email, #listing_owner_mobile" ).change(function() {
    disableProposalBtn();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: if you need jquery in your rails app, you can add it as such:  https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails